# BASH; using find and -exec to remove .pyc files

Tags: bash, python-2.7, ubuntu, pyc

Using the command line in Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS. I'm getting towards the end of Zed Shaw's LPTHW, and on the video to ex46.py he exercises the following bash command to find and remove all .pyc byte code files:

```
find . -name "*.pyc" -exec rm {}
```

On the video this successfully removes all of Zed Shaw's .pyc files. However, upon typing in the exact same command I get the following error:

```
find: missing argument to `-exec'
```

I understand that there are many ways to delete .pyc files, however, since I'm following along with Zed Shaw I'd like to know how to do it using find and -exec. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could leverage using `-delete` over `-exec rm` as the former does not spawn a new process for each of the file instance to delete. Also you could chip in the `-type f` option to apply the operation for files only.

```
find . -type f -name "*.pyc" -delete
```

Answer (score 4):

you need to terminate the `-exec` command with `\;`

```
find . -name "*.pyc" -exec rm {} \;
```

have a look at [`find -exec`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/find) in the man page.

as mentioned in the comments by [Gordon Davisson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/89817/gordon-davisson) it may be more efficient to terminate the command with `+` as `rm` is then invoked fewer times:

```
find . -name "*.pyc" -exec rm {} +
```

Comment: You can also use `-exec rm {} +` to delete them in batches instead of running `rm` separately for each file.

Comment: I thought the \ was just a line break; I didn't even see the semicolon.